# How to change page size dynamically in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am having a Kendo UI grid showing more than 1000 data. I also have a dropdown list for different page size - 15, 25, 50, 100. On selection of a page size, how can we change the page size of Kendo UI grid?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set the page size in the combobox change event. (Also see [JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/umejit/edit#source).)

```
$("#comboBox").kendoComboBox({
    dataTextField: "text",
    dataValueField: "value",
    dataSource: [
        { text: 1 },
        { text: 2 },
        { text: 3 },
        { text: 4 },
        { text: 5 }
    ],
    change: function(e) {
      var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
      grid.dataSource.pageSize(parseInt(this.value()));  // this.value() being the value selected in Combo
    }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

Here's the latest using ASP.NET MVC Helper

```
.Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] {20, 50, 100})) // Enable paging
```

Comment: That's great.  Any idea how you could add 'All'?

Comment: @DavidC did you ever figure out how to add 'All' option?

Comment: `.Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] { 20, 50, 100, "All" }))`

Comment: @RichC, Adding "All" to an int[] throws an error. If I add 0, it will show all. I'm still trying to figure out how to add "All" using razor without having to use  extra javascript to do it.

Comment: Ah - might can only do it in javascript... `$("#pager").kendoPager({
      dataSource: dataSource,
      pageSizes: [2, 3, 4, "all"]
    });`

Answer (score 15):

Its also built into the latest version of the grid by doing the following in js

```
pageable: {
    pageSizes: [10, 25, 50, 100]
}
```

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/pager

Answer (score 2):

Rick has told it in a good way a more explained if some one misses where is it to be done here is a code piece to know where is it to be done  with a screen short [snap](http://prntscr.com/4ukkcs)

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("SiteUserGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
          {
              columns.Bound(u => u.LastName).Title("Last Name");
              columns.Bound(u => u.FirstName).Title("First Name");
              columns.Bound(u => u.UserName).Title("User Name");
              columns.Bound(u => u.EmailAddress).Title("Email Address");
              columns.Bound(u => u.AccessLevel).Title("Access Level");
              columns.Bound(u => u.Status).Title("Status");
              columns.Bound(u => u.UserId).Filterable(f => f.Enabled(false)).ClientTemplate(actionColumnTemplate).Title("Action").Sortable(false).Width(190);
          })
      .Pageable(pageable => pageable.ButtonCount(10))
```

### .Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new int[] {5,10,15,20,30,50,100}))

```
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single))
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable(filterable => filterable
                                    .Extra(false)
                                    .Operators(operators => operators
                                                                .ForString(str => str.Clear()
                                                                                     .StartsWith("Starts with")
                                                                                     .Contains("Contains")
                                                                                     .IsEqualTo("Is equal to")
                                                                ))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

To expand on [Rick Glos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17582299/1677912):

You can set the Pageable PageSizes to an array of generic objects, so you can have an "All" option without having to set pageSizes in JavaScript.

```
.Pageable(pager => pager.PageSizes(new object[] {20, 50, 100, "All"}))
```

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.kendoui.com/api/wrappers/php/Kendo/UI/GridPageable

```
$pageable = new \Kendo\UI\GridPageable();
$pageable->pageSizes(array(20,50,100));
```